# *seamless* synchronization between remote computers?

Tags: windows, sync

I have a desktop PC (windows 7) here in my office, and a laptop (windows 10). I want to synchronize files and folders between them, both for the obvious purpose of having all my most recent work readily available to me, and also for syncing program files such as Sublime Text and my Firefox profile. Solutions so far tried:

- Dropbox
- Btsync (using a Raspberry pi as an intermediary node point)

The perennial problem I seem to face is that all of these programs have built-in 
version-control systems (because they always seem to assume that it's going to be some office full of people using these things that are liable to be stupid enough to carelessly overwrite each other's work) ie. in the case of Dropbox, I end up with hundreds of "confilcted copy" duplicates- with no way of disabling this feature - so that's out the window. To my disappointment, I now seem to be running into a similar problem with BtSync (which I really thought was going to be the answer); it doesn't seem to respect deleted files, and instead immediately starts downloading them again from the secondary device, rather than DELETING them from the secondary device!

What I want is *seamless* integration between my computers- no version control, no nonsense- when I make a file, that file appears on the other computer. When I change it, it changes. When I delete it, it's gone- on all devices. End of story.

I would prefer a solution that doesn't require both my computers to be on at the same time; so either a cloud-based solution or something which can utilize my Raspberry Pi.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you’ve never accidentally deleted a file? Impressive! Synchronization conflicts are entirely unrelated to file versioning, however. They are unavoidable.

Comment: Why are they unavoidable? And why is what I am asking for such an insurmountable task?

Comment: Because you don’t have one resource but two. Each can be updated individually. If, between synchronizations, they were both to be updated, you get a conflict. Simple as that. What you want cannot be achieved with synchronization. Instead, you must use exactly one resource. One example of that would be Windows File Sharing.

Comment: "If, between synchronizations, they were both to be updated, you get a conflict. Simple as that"

Then I want to always overwrite the older file with the most recent one. Simple as that. Do I really have to consign myself to the reality that there are *no* solutions out there, anywhere, that can achieve this? Staggering.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Windows File Sharing, however it seems that comes with its own security issues etc when accessing remotely. I also need a solution that can utilize an intermediary node point, thereby negating the need for both my machines to be on simultaneously. It seems a NAS drive could be a solution to that, though I'm certiainly not buying one just for that task until I know it will all work as I want.

Comment: For anyone reading this, please note that Daniel B is incorrect in his assertion that synchronization conflicts are unavoidable. BTSync is indeed a viable solution to this problem and will always overwrite an older file with a newer version. Please see my answer below.

Comment: And how did you determine that "take newest" isn't a conflict resolution method? Again: conflicts are unavoidable. They can be resolved without human intervention, of course. "Take newest" is obviously a destructive way to do this.

Comment: I see, so conflicts are unavoidable... but can be resolved instantly and automatically so I don't have to care about it... I'm not sure what point you are trying to make then. What did you think this question was asking? With all due respect I came here to seek a practical solution to my problem and your inital comments make it sound like no such solution exists. Now youre saying "[conflicts] can be resolved without human intervention "Take newest" is obviously a destructive way to do this" Yet you clearly wrote "What you want cannot be achieved with synchronization" -which is evidently false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found was indeed BTSync running on a Raspberry Pi. The problem in my case was that the correct read & write permissions weren't set on all the folders. If you have the time and  patience, I highly recommend trying this as a convenient alternative to Dropbox. Get started [here](https://blog.getsync.com/2015/09/04/sync-wd-raspberry-pi/).

Regarding file conflicts, as far as I know, the only way this can happen with BTSync is in situations where files have the same name but with different letter case. Eg. [from the help docs](http://sync-help.bittorrent.com/customer/portal/articles/1596830-conflict-files-in-sync):

> This may occur for a variety of reasons:
>
> When a file (FIlename.jpg) is trying to get synced from one case-insensitive system to a folder in a case-insensitive system, where a file (filename.jpeg) is already present, the latter will produce a conflict file (filename.Conflict.jpg).
>
> When a file has the same name, but with a different letter case in Unix.

However, there is no version-control as such, and so in cases that might normally produce a conflict in other systems (ie. 2 copies of the file have both been updated between synchronizations), then [the solution is simple](https://www.quora.com/How-does-bittorrent-sync-handle-conflicts-if-the-same-file-is-found-to-have-changed-on-both-ends-during-a-sync):

> BitTorrent Sync checks file change time in UTC format, the newer file wins.

Answer (score 0):

I use the good old DOS batch command   XCOPY  with the update function. I have written my own utility program that Maps other computers then it  gives me the ability to create a batch file that uses Xcopy in various ways.
A typical command would be
xcopy "C:\Sendtext" "N:\Sendtext" /D /Y /R  /exclude:c:\Batch\noxcopy.txt

This copies files from   the C drive folder Sendtext to the N drive folder Sendtext.  The /D tells xcopy only to copy newer files, the /Y suppresses any query about overwriting and the /R would overwrite any read only file.  The Exclude file noxcopy.txt  tells xcopy what NOT to copy (you have to create a list in the noxcopy.txt file).

There are other options for xcopy, such as doing a test run, and copying subdirectories.  Use XCOPY /? in DOS to see them all.

Obviously you would need to run this on a regular basis to provide a real time update, the only other option may be to write a utility to detect any updates, then copying the files over.

Answer (score 0):

Owncloud [can works on PI](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Owncloud-dropbox-clone/) and you can [disable its version control system](http://en.flossmanuals.net/owncloud/tasks/) but "seamless" synchronization will require much effort in its configuration.

You can also check [Wikipedia synchronization software comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_synchronization_software).